# Can't choose Ubuntu after installing alongside Windows

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows-10

I have a laptop with Windows installed on its NVMe SSD **HFM256GDHTNG-8310A**and I installed Ubuntu 18.04.4 on the 1 TB HDD **ATA WDC WD10SPZX-24Z**. I don't use virtualization. After restarting, I don't see Ubuntu installed.

The result of `sudo parted -l` is

```
Model: ATA WDC WD10SPZX-24Z (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  1050MB  1049MB  primary   fat32        boot
 2      1050MB  900GB   899GB   primary   ntfs
 3      900GB   1000GB  100GB   extended
 5      900GB   1000GB  100GB   logical   ext4


Model: Kingston DataTraveler 3.0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 62.0GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      32.3kB  62.0GB  62.0GB  primary  ntfs         boot
 2      62.0GB  62.0GB  32.3kB  primary


Model: HFM256GDHTNG-8310A (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 256GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  255GB  255GB  primary  ntfs         boot
 2      255GB   256GB  634MB  primary  ntfs         diag
```

Plz, help me to be able to start Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes it's the usb I used

Comment: @K7AAY Should the new partition be ext4

Comment: Thanks. the problem is solved. If U write the comments as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest a reboot from the LiveUSB . Use its **gparted** program to delete the ext4 partition /dev/sda5; click the green checkmark on the icon bar.

Delete the Extended partition /dev/sda3; click the green checkmark on the icon bar.

Make a new Primary **ext4** partition in that 100GB space on /dev/sda and click the green checkmark on the icon bar before exiting from gparted.

Restart the installation and when you get to step 6 tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#5 choose **Something else** and reinstall Ubuntu into that 100 GB space. Use it for root.

After install completes, it should prompt you to remove the LiveUSB before rebooting. A successful install shows you the [GRUB menu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2) where you can choose Ubuntu or Windows. If you still don't see it, go back into windows and [disable Fast Start](http://computerhope.com/issues/ch001762.htm) then reboot.